# vba can not find opening IE 11 Browser.

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a vba code which can upload the data from an excel sheet to a website. However, the code works fine in Win7 System and  IE browser 8,but it does not work on a win8 IE browser 11. 
Here are part of the code:

```
   Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlFrame As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement
    Dim frame As HTMLIFrame
    Dim htmlElement As HTMLDTElement
    Dim myDoc As Object


    Set curSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set oShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    For Each oWin In oShApp.Windows

    If oWin.Name = "Windows Internet Explorer" Then
        Set IE = oWin
        Exit For
    End If

Next

If IE Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Please sign into Avocado, then re-run this macro")
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.google.com"
    Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("Prepare").Select
fPathName = Cells(5, 5)
Call MakeFolders(fPathName)
Call MakeFolders2(fPathName)
Call MakeFolders3(fPathName)
'fFileName = fPathName & "\*.xls"
fFileName = Dir(fPathName & "\*.xls")
```

The code runs in a loop when enters the statement : "If IE Is Nothing Then"
Even when the google site is opened, the program still keeps prompting out the msgBox, and reopen the website again and again, and it never executes to the last part "Sheets("Prepare").Select".  I am very confused because it works perfect in the IE 8 browsers. I am wondering if there is any difference between IE11 and IE8 in terms of vba IE function. 
Please take a look up it and give me some ideas on this, your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the identical problem and found, that the window name of the shell.application has changed in IE 11. Earlier versions had the name "Windows Internet Explorer", but IE 11 uses only "Internet Explorer"

If you change your if condition accordingly, it will work again ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The macro works in IE11 again, but if the excel is in version 2010, the ie.document.getElementById function will cause a "object required error". Do you know a way can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an old version of internet explorer. Use the code I provided bellow and see if it works. Please make sure you have the following references added to your project:

- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- Microsoft Internet Controls.

If you are not sure how to add the references to your code check out this link.[External References](http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-reference-libraries-in-excel-workbook/)

```
Sub Test()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlFrame As HTMLFrameElement
    Dim frame As HTMLIFrame
    Dim htmlElement As HTMLDTElement
    Dim myDoc As Object
    Dim curSheet As Worksheet


    ' Set the variables
    Set curSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    ' Make the browser visible and navigate
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.google.com"
    End With

    WaitForInternetToLoad objIE


    Sheets("Prepare").Select
    fPathName = Cells(5, 5).Value
    Call MakeFolders(fPathName)
    Call MakeFolders2(fPathName)
    Call MakeFolders3(fPathName)
    'fFileName = fPathName & "\*.xls"
    fFileName = Dir(fPathName & "\*.xls")


End Sub

Sub WaitForInternetToLoad(ByRef ie As InternetExplorer)
    Do
        dovents
    Loop While Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End Sub
```

## Extra Information.

Hi I see you are having some trouble with this and I want to extend my help.

Let's start by the fact that you are using two external libraries in your code; and you should have references set to them for the code to work properly. See my picture I have highlighted the libraries yellow. 
[image: Libraries References]

What are the differences:

### Microsoft Internet Controls

Is the one that takes care of the internet object. It creates an internet explorer application and it navigates to certain links. Once it finishes navigating to the url then " internet object" has a "**document**". This object cannot do anything else.

### Microsoft HTML Object Library

This library takes care of the Html document. And as you probably guessed you will assign the "**document**" from the previous object (internet explorer) to a HTML document variable and then you can do further manipulation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The code you provided can execute to the call function, However, it will get errors in the rest of the code. This is a project with several modules. Do I have to change every "ie" in the code to "objIE"?

Comment: It's hard to tell for the other modules but all objIE should be declared as "Dim objIE As InternetExplorer" Also make sure that if you are navigating to a page you use the way I used in the code and always call the procedure "waitForInternetToLoad" after each navagation

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The code you provided can execute to the call function, However, it will get errors in the rest of the code. This is a project with several modules. Do I have to change every "ie" in the code to "objIE"? And the declaration like " 'If oWin.Name = "Windows Internet Explorer" Then  'Set IE = oWin" Will all need to be deleted.So I am wondering, for Internet Explore 11, does it has a different name from Internet Explore 8? I am afraid the changes will dysfunction other part of the program.

Comment: I am not sure what the difference is though. You can remove that conditional too; keep in mind that is some has an older version of internet explorer the code might now work for them.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but after I changed the code, the function:  objIE.document.getElementById("RLPM_TYPE").Value = 2 does not work, the error message is error'424' "object required". Since the getElementById function is built in, so I am wondering if there is any other name for this function in IE11? Thank you

Comment: Also, my IE is version 11.0.24, it installs new version automatically, it is company's computer.

Comment: I added more information above. Also for your problem you cannot access the HTML document directly from the internet you need a variable for this. Try something like  Set myDoc = objIE.document and the use the getElementByID function.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The external libraries were included at the first place. After I add :Set myDoc = objIE.document, the getElementByID function still doesnt work

Comment: This is a far as I dare to go. I have no clue without looking at the code.